# Hibernate unidirectional OneToMany delete violates constraint ( optional=false at parent side?)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I use Hibernate 3.6 and I have something like this:

```
@Entity 
public class Parent { 
    @OnyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { ascadeType.ALL } )   
    @Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE )   
    @JoinColumn( name="Parent_ID" )
    public List<Child> getChildren() { return children; }   
public void setChildren( List<Child> children ) { this.children = children; }
private transient List<TitleMetadataCategory> children;
...
 }

@Entity
public class Child {
....
}
```

Association is unidirectional for several reasons and I don't want to change it . In addition orphan children don't exist, so there is DB constraint that CHILD.PARENT_ID is not null. 
All works fine, except removing child. When I do

`parent.getChildren().remove(child);
 session.saveOrUpdate(parent)`.

it fails.

Since I don't have

```
@ManyToOne( optional=false )
```

at the child side Hibernate tries to update child with PARENT_ID=NULL and fails due to DB constraint.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Unidirectional hibernate doesn't allow to map association to the entity that has not connections.

Comment: It has connected by Child.Parent_ID column in DB  as mapped

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
@JoinColumn(name = "Parent_ID", nullable = false)
```

?

Also, note that attached entities are automatically persistent. You don't need to call `saveOrUpdate()`.

Comment: I've tried it and get
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity PARENT_ID
Exception

Comment: Then it means you've mapped the parentId column in the child table. You shouldn't, as it's already mapped as a join column in the parent table. If the child knows about its parent, then make it a bidirectional association. If it doesn't know about it, then it shouldn't map the parent_id column. And you indeed need orphan removal as well.

Comment: Yes I have few biderectional mappings with orphan removal and it works. However, parent have about 15 types of children with its own children in some of them. I'm quite fear to define bidirectional  mapping for each one, since I'm already had some cascade confilcts.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of JB Nizet is working, but with one correction. Since I also have Child.getParentId() method ( not getParent() ), its Column annotation should have `nullable=false, insertable=false, updateble=false` parameters in addition to `nullable=false, updatable=false` in Parent.getChildren() association.

Answer (score 0):

With the current configuration Hibernate doesn't know that the `Child` has to be deleted when you remove it from `children` collection (it's called orphan removal). You need `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)` in the parent. `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE` only specifies that child should be deleted too when the entire parent is deleted.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work, since hibernate first schedules update action and only after that checking if it is orphan and schedules delete action. As results there is delete action in queue, but update throws exception before.

Comment: Then try it together with `@JoinColumn(name = "Parent_ID", nullable = false)` suggested by JB Nizet