# How to cascade remove object from database with @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a simple question. I have `User` and `Log`.

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @Column
   private String login;
   @Column
   private String password;
}

@Entity
public class Log {
   @Column
   private int type;
   @ManyToOne()
   @JoinColumn(name="user")
   private User user;
}
```

Problem is, when I want to remove object `User`, it wont allow me to do it because of `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: **Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails**`. How to set behaviour to delete all `Log` objects when removing `User` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need [bidirectional](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional) assotiation.
See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168209/hibernate-delete-row-and-foreign-key-row-manytoone) in stackoverflow.

Comment: I believe that this is not my scenario, because I have only Unidirectional mapping. I have more this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380167/hibernate-unidirectional-onetomany-delete-violates-constraint-optional-false-a

Comment: OK, this is solution for my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197181/jpa-unidirectional-many-to-one-and-cascading-delete